# Filter the records through hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have used 8 different field filters into my application those are selected from eight different dropdowns ,now I am wishing to get the data accordingly the dropdown selected values.now if I have selected one value from the dropdown then  it will fetch the data as per selected value,and rest of the fields are empty , if i select one another field then it will check the both field values,rest of the fields are empty and it will fetch the result from the database.to do so i have made a single query to fetch the data that is

```
public List<Companies> getFilteredData(int start,
                                int length,
                                String companyName,
                                String state,
                                Integer empId,
                                String country,
                                String website,
                                Integer pTech,
                                Integer sTech,
                                Integer status){


Criteria cr=factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Companies.class);
cr.createAlias("primTech","primTech");
cr.createAlias("secondTech","secondTech");
cr.createAlias("statuss","statuss");
cr.createAlias("employee","employee");

cr.add(Restrictions.and(

          Restrictions.or(  
          Restrictions.eq("companyName",companyName),
          Restrictions.isNotNull("companyName"))
    ,
    Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.eq("state",state),
            Restrictions.isNotNull("state")),

       Restrictions.or(
               Restrictions.eq("employee.id",empId),
               Restrictions.isNotNull("employee.id")),

       Restrictions.or(
               Restrictions.eq("country",country),
               Restrictions.isNotNull("country"))
       ,
       Restrictions.or(
               Restrictions.eq("website",website),
               Restrictions.isNotNull("website"))
       ,
       Restrictions.or( 
               Restrictions.eq("primTech.id",pTech)
               ,Restrictions.isNotNull("primTech.id"))
     ,
     Restrictions.or(
             Restrictions.eq("secondTech.id",sTech),
             Restrictions.isNotNull("secondTech.id"))
      ,
      Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("statuss.id",status),
              Restrictions.isNotNull("statuss.id"))

        ));


return cr.list();

}
```

this list returns the empty values in all those cases as I mentioned above.
here You are my POJO class,

```
@Entity
@Table 
public class Companies implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String companyName;
private String website;
private String contactName;
private String jobTitle;
private String address;
private String city;
private String pin;
private String country;
private String empSize;
private String state;
private String businessDomain;
private double rating;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "primTechID")
private PrimaryTech primTech;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "secondTechID")
private SecondaryTech secondTech;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "statusID")
private Status statuss;

private String phoneNo;
private String mobileNo;
private String email;
private Date datee;
private String description;
private String skyp;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee employee;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="companies",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<ContactedBy> contactedBy = new ArrayList<ContactedBy>();
```

here is my controller side,

```
@RequestMapping("admin/getdynamic")
public @ResponseBody 
String dataProcessing(@RequestParam int draw, 
                      @RequestParam int start,
                      @RequestParam int length,
                      @RequestParam(required=false) Integer tech,
                      @RequestParam(required=false)Integer sec,
                      @RequestParam(required=false)Integer emp,
                      @RequestParam String cont,
                      @RequestParam String state,
                      @RequestParam(required=false)Integer status,
                      @RequestParam String url,
                      @RequestParam String compName,
                      Model model){



    JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
    ObjectNode objectNode = factory.objectNode();


List<Companies> list = companyService.getFilteredData(start,length,compName, state, emp, cont, url, tech, sec, status);
    ArrayNode node = factory.arrayNode();
    objectNode.set("data", node);

        list.forEach(lists -> {

            ArrayNode arr = factory.arrayNode();    
            arr.add(lists.getId());
            arr.add(lists.getCompanyName());
            arr.add(lists.getEmail());
            arr.add(lists.getContactName());
            arr.add(lists.getWebsite());
            arr.add(lists.getPrimTech().getName());
            arr.add(lists.getJobTitle());
            arr.add(lists.getPhoneNo());
            arr.add("<td><input type='checkbox' name='chkbox' id='chekbox' class='chekbox'/></td>");
            arr.add("<td width='40'><a class='creativeButton squareBlueButton editButton ct_edit_group' onClick='onUpdateClick("+lists.getId()+")'></a><a class='creativeButton squareRedButton closeButton'onClick='onDeleteClick("+lists.getId()+")'></a></td>");

            node.add(arr);
        });



     objectNode.put("draw", draw);
     objectNode.put("recordsTotal", companyService.getFilteredData(start,length,compName, state, emp, cont, url, tech, sec, status).size());
     objectNode.put("recordsFiltered", companyService.companyService.getFilteredData(start,length,compName, state, emp, cont, url, tech, sec, status).size());

    return objectNode.toString();
}
```

Awaiting for your answer as soon as possible..
Thanks..

here the query fired by hibernate,notice the query from the end..

```
/* criteria query */ select this_.id as id1_0_7_, this_.Status_Count as Status_C2_0_7_, this_.address as address3_0_7_, this_.businessDomain as business4_0_7_, this_.city as city5_0_7_, this_.companyName as companyN6_0_7_, this_.contactName as contactN7_0_7_, this_.country as country8_0_7_, this_.datee as datee9_0_7_, this_.description as descrip10_0_7_, this_.email as email11_0_7_, this_.empSize as empSize12_0_7_, this_.employee_id as employe21_0_7_, this_.jobTitle as jobTitl13_0_7_, this_.mobileNo as mobileN14_0_7_, this_.phoneNo as phoneNo15_0_7_, this_.pin as pin16_0_7_, this_.primTechID as primTec22_0_7_, this_.rating as rating17_0_7_, this_.secondTechID as secondT23_0_7_, this_.skyp as skyp18_0_7_, this_.state as state19_0_7_, this_.statusID as statusI24_0_7_, this_.website as website20_0_7_, employee4_.id as id1_2_0_, employee4_.Report_to as Report_t7_2_0_, employee4_.email as email2_2_0_, employee4_.firstName as firstNam3_2_0_, employee4_.lastName as lastName4_2_0_, employee4_.password as password5_2_0_, employee4_.roleID as roleID8_2_0_, employee4_.username as username6_2_0_, employee7_.id as id1_2_1_, employee7_.Report_to as Report_t7_2_1_, employee7_.email as email2_2_1_, employee7_.firstName as firstNam3_2_1_, employee7_.lastName as lastName4_2_1_, employee7_.password as password5_2_1_, employee7_.roleID as roleID8_2_1_, employee7_.username as username6_2_1_, employeero8_.id as id1_3_2_, employeero8_.name as name2_3_2_, primtech1_.id as id1_4_3_, primtech1_.name as name2_4_3_, secondtech2_.id as id1_7_4_, secondtech2_.name as name2_7_4_, statuss3_.id as id1_8_5_, statuss3_.name as name2_8_5_, statuss3_.categoryId as category3_8_5_, statuscate12_.id as id1_9_6_, statuscate12_.categoryName as category2_9_6_ from Companies this_ inner join Employee employee4_ on this_.employee_id=employee4_.id left outer join Employee employee7_ on employee4_.Report_to=employee7_.id left outer join EmployeeRole employeero8_ on employee4_.roleID=employeero8_.id inner join PrimaryTech primtech1_ on this_.primTechID=primtech1_.id inner join SecondaryTech secondtech2_ on this_.secondTechID=secondtech2_.id inner join Status statuss3_ on this_.statusID=statuss3_.id left outer join StatusCategory statuscate12_ on statuss3_.categoryId=statuscate12_.id where ((this_.companyName is not null and this_.companyName=? and (this_.state is not null) and this_.state=? and (employee4_.id is not null) and employee4_.id=? and (this_.country is not null) and this_.country=? and (this_.website is not null) and this_.website=? and (primtech1_.id is not null) and primtech1_.id=? and (secondtech2_.id is not null) and secondtech2_.id=? and (statuss3_.id is not null) and statuss3_.id=?))
```

Comment: Have you seen the generated query in your logs? Keen on seeing that

Comment: You are performing a lot of joins .. Thats not a good thing to do

Comment: why lot of joins are not good?

Comment: it increases the time that your query will take to run and also will result you lot of duplicate rows .. Many database does not even allow joins of more that 5 tables

Comment: You're awaiting answers but... what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      public List<Companies> getFilteredData(int start,
            int length,
            String companyName,
            String state,
            Integer empId,
            String country,
            String website,
            Integer pTech,
            Integer sTech,
            Integer status){



      List<Criterion> criterionList=new ArrayList<Criterion>();

      if(null!=companyName && !companyName.isEmpty())
          criterionList.add(Restrictions.like("companyName",companyName));
     if(null!=state && !state.isEmpty())
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.like("state",state));
     if(null!=empId )
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.eq("employee.id",empId));
     if(null!=country && !country.isEmpty())
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.like("country",country));
     if(null!=website && !website.isEmpty())
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.like("website",website));
     if(null!=pTech )
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.eq("primTech.id",pTech));
     if(null!=sTech )
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.eq("secondTech.id",sTech));
     if(null!=status )
         criterionList.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("statuss.id",status));

         Criteria cr=factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Companies.class);
         cr.createAlias("primTech","primTech");
         cr.createAlias("secondTech","secondTech");
         cr.createAlias("statuss","statuss");
         cr.createAlias("employee","employee");

         if(null!=criterionList && !criterionList.isEmpty())
             for(Criterion criterion:criterionList)
                 if(null!=criterion)
                     cr.add(criterion);


         return cr.list();

  }
```

This should solve you problem.

The above method is adding criterion for an argument if its not null in a list of criterion . At the end it is adding all the criterion present in the list to the Criteria query. In this way it will add restriction only for those arguments whose value has been passed to this method.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Zulfi, I did run this code into my system but still I am getting zero list.

Comment: @Pranav change the eq restriction for string into like restrictions .. check edit on my answer above

Comment: @Pranav .. You are welcome ..please also accept the answer :)